# Glossary Dual entries printed together

Tags: glossaries, acronyms

With a dual entry I am able to both list Glossary and Acronyms in the same command

```latex
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {
  \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
    description={#6},#1
  }
  \makeglossaries
  \newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{gls-#3}},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}
}
```

I've created the following minimal viable product

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[acronym,nonumberlist]{glossaries}

\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {
  \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
    description={#6},#1
  }
  \makeglossaries
  \newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{gls-#3}},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}
}

\makeglossaries

\newdualentry{st}{ST}{Sample Test}{This is a sample test}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum \gls{st}

\printglossary[type=\acronymtype]
\printglossary

\end{document}
```

Which produces a text, with the acronym entry, and lastly it includes a section called acronyms and glossaries.

[image: Example output]

I would like the output of the Acronym and Glossary to be together, such that I get firstly the acronym, and then the definition of the word, just like so (or at least similarly):

**Acronym and Glossary:**

**ST** - **Sample Test** This is a sample test.

Comment: Have you tried `name={#4 -- #5}` in the `\newglossaryentry` command?

Comment: If you add this as an answer, I'll reward you with the bounty @gernot

Comment: Thanks, very generous, but this simple answer does not deserve the bounty. I will make it an answer, then you can accept it to close this "issue", but please keep the bounty. You may need it for more complicated questions.

Comment: Well, you'd receive the bounty after seven days anyhow. :-)

Comment: As far as I know there is no automatism. You can decide after seven days whether you want to grant the bounty or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the acronym to the name of the glossary entry: `name={#4 -- #5}` instead of `name={#5}`, i.e.,

```
\DeclareDocumentCommand{\newdualentry}{ O{} O{} m m m m } {
  \newglossaryentry{gls-#3}{name={#4 -- #5},text={#5\glsadd{#3}},
    description={#6},#1
  }
  \makeglossaries
  \newacronym[see={[Glossary:]{gls-#3}},#2]{#3}{#4}{#5\glsadd{gls-#3}}
}
```